# Xamarin UI Test Android: How to put the app background for some time and then again launch it with out creating new instance?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I'm automating android application, I want to put the app in background for some time and then want to launch the existing application.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get accurate answers, you should write what is your target and what problem is making you stuck, attach the portion of code interested and also explain what you've tried to solve the issues

Answer (score 0):

To minimize/background the app, you can try this:

`MoveTaskToBack(true)` or `app.Invoke("BackgroundBackdoor");`

And then you can use a timer to do a wait. Then to reopen the app from the existing instance instead of a new one, you can try this:

`ConfigureApp.Android.ConnectToApp()`